# How to manage sentry configs (api key etc) in bare react-native app?

Tags: react-native, sentry

I have added sentry to a react native app (ejected from expo).
The sentry wizard created two `sentry.properties` files in `android` and `ios` folders. These files contain an `auth.token` field which is secret and should not be committed.
If I leave the value blank, ios build won't compile. So it seems the key needs to be populated at build time form some `.env` or something.

What is the intended way to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Safely handling API keys and other sensitive data is a topic called **Secret Management**.

Here is an OWASP doc that covers [**Where should a secret be?**](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Secrets_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#32-where-should-a-secret-be)

> There are various places where you can store a secret to execute CI/CD actions:
>
> As part of your CI/CD tooling: you can store a secret in GitLab/GitHub/jenkins. This is not the same as committing it to code.

https://owasp.org/ has lots of good info about securing apps.